# hash function type and

Tags: hash

What kind of Hash function is this? and what does it do?

```
hash[i] = 999999999;
sort(adj[i].begin(), adj[i].end());
for(int j = 0;j < adj[i].size();j++)
{
    hash[i] += (hash[i]*hash[adj[i][j]])%mod;
    hash[i] %= mod;
}
```

Comment: You ask what hash does? It is an encryption without a decryption method.

Comment: i know that dude!
i'm asking why isn't it like other hash functions.

Comment: I looks like a custom made hash. I'm not even sure if this IS a hash ;)